# UITableViewCell With image custom size

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimageview

I'm loading an image in to an UITableView through a simple

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"prem.jpg"];
```

However, what I've learnt from my limited time with xcode things arent normally that easy! I want to have the image in there take up the fullsize of the image which is about 280 wide and 150 tall. From googling I might have to build a custom cell and put the image in there and then load that custom cell? I've not done anything like that before and it seems a bit annoying just to load one image. Is there an alternative?

To put in context, I have 3 sections in the tableview top section will be the image, and the other two are arrays loaded from XML files. If I do a custom cell I have to do a seperate xml call to get the image url before it goes through so I'd really like to avoid that if possible?

Really looking for any pointers you can offer. Thanks a lot

Tom

Edit: cellforrowindexpath as requsted:

```
 (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if(indexPath.section == 0)


        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"prem.jpg"];




    if(indexPath.section == 1)

        cell.textLabel.text = [arryTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    else if(indexPath.section == 2)
        cell.textLabel.text = [arryTableActions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;


}
```

Comment: Please include your cellForRowAtIndexPath method in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to create a custom cell subclass. I am assuming you have a single cell in section 0 and a variable number of cells in sections 1 and 2.

You should be using a different cell reuse identifier for your cell in section 0 as it contains an image view and the others don't - this will show up in your later sections when the cells are recycled otherwise.

I'd try something like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{      
    static NSString *CellIdentifierText = @"TextCell";
    static NSString *CellIdentifierImage = @"ImageCell";

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierImage];
        // I am assuming this image never changes and there is one row in this section! If it does change, use viewWithTag to get hold of the image view.
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierImage] autorelease];
                   UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,250,180)];              
                   myImageView.tag = 1;
             myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"prem.jpg"];
            [cell addSubview:myImageView];
                       [myImageView release];
        }
        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierText];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierText] autorelease];
        }      
        if(indexPath.section == 1)          
            cell.textLabel.text = [arryTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];       
        else if(indexPath.section == 2)         
            cell.textLabel.text = [arryTableActions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];      
        return cell;   
    }
}
```

Make sure you are adding the image to the newly created image view and **not** cell.imageView as the latter is a read-only property which is over to the left side, I'm not sure you can resize it.

You will also need to set the height for your cell, as it is taller than the standard. This will be in the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method.

Comment: Hey - Thanks a lot for this! I've added it to my code, (and it makes sense to me!) but theres a small issue, it still has the small image to the left as if it was expecting text to the right and seems to have ignored the size parameters?

Comment: Yeah it is squished to the left

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the customCells.Means take an image view (whatever size you want.).And add it to the cell in cellforIndexpath method.

Comment: Subclass UITableViewCell. In your subclass add a UIImageView. Use that subclass in your table. Here is a great tutorial: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Comment: Thanks for that. So you're saying I do have to create a custom tableviewcell?